# asp.net div scrollbar missing on Windows Phone emulator only

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, scrollbar

I am trying to learn asp.net so please forgive me if this is a simple mistake I'm making. I'm creating web pages that will run on a desktop and mobile device. I'm using WebMatrix to test the pages for both iPhone and Windows Phone 7. I have a grid view that needs a scrollbar so I put it inside a div tag as follows:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
                            <asp:GridView ID="grdBarrel" runat="server" Height="232px">
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                        </div>
```

The scrollbar appears as expected on my desktop and on the iPhone emulator in WebMatrix, but it does not show up on the Windows Phone 7 empulator in WebMatrix.
[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsRu.jpg)

As you can see from the image, the scrollbar does show on all but the Windows Phone 7 emulator. I have tried changing the overflow to scroll but that did not help.

Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gina

Comment: Id consider whether fixing issues for windows phone 7 (and the emulator at that) is worth it. Saying that can you add a min height greater than the container div to force the scroll like <asp:GridView ID="grdBarrel" Style=""min-height:300px" ...

Comment: I tried your suggestion and made the height of the grid view 300px (taller than the div) but I still don't get the scrollbar. This app will eventually be used on Motorola barcode scanners (Windows Mobile 6 and Windows Mobile 6.5) but I have not been able to locate an emulator in WebMatrix for those, so I'm thinking the closest I can get is the Windows Phone 7. That's the only reason I'm using that emulator but if you know a better solution, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: overflow-y:scroll;  ? If that doesn't work I give up :)

Comment: I already tried that. It makes both a horizontal and vertical scrollbar show up on all but the Windows Phone emulator :-(